# How can i read all the lines from a text file in specific places and use the data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\wmiclasses\wmiclasses1.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
     {
        if (lines[i].StartsWith("ComboBox"))
           {

           }
      }
```

And this is how the text file content look like:

```
ComboBox Name cmbxOption

Classes Win32_1394Controller
Classes Win32_1394ControllerDevice

ComboBox Name cmbxStorage

Classes Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting
Classes Win32_TapeDrive
```

What I need to do is some things:

1. Each time the line start with `ComboBox` then to get only the `ComboBox` name from the line for example `cmbxOption`.

Since I have already this `ComboBoxes` in my `form1` designer I need to identify where the `cmbxOption` start and end and when the next `ComboBox` start `cmbxStorage`.

2. To get all the lines of the current `ComboBox` for example this lines belong to `cmbxOption`:

   Classes Win32_1394Controller
       Classes Win32_1394ControllerDevice
3. To create from each line a Key and Value for example from the line:

   Classes Win32_1394Controller

Then the key will be `Win32_1394Controller` and the value will be only `1394Controller`

Then the second line key `Win32_1394ControllerDevice` and value only `1394ControllerDevice`

4. To add to the correct belonging ComboBox only the value `1394Controller`.
5. To make that when I select in the `ComboBox` for example in `cmbxOption` the item `1394Controller` it will act like I selected `Win32_1394Controller`.

For example in this event:

```
 private void cmbxOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    InsertInfo(cmbxOption.SelectedItem.ToString(), reflstDisplayHardware, chkHardware.Checked);

    }
```

In need that the `SelectedItem` will be `Win32_1394Controller` but the user will see in the `cmbxOption` only `1394Controller` without the `Win32_`

This is the start of the method InsertInfo

```
  private void InsertInfo(string Key, ref ListView lst, bool DontInsertNull)
            {
```

That's why i need that the Key will be Win32_1394Controller but i want that the user will see in the `ComboBox` only `1394Controller` without the `Win32_`

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far and what are your specific problems? stackoverflow is not about getting your job done for you for free, it's about helping programmers solve specific problems.

Comment: Add your efforts here to show that you have tried something (at least). This place is not to hire someone and get your work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some quick ugly code:

```
class Group<T> : List<T>, IGrouping<T, T>
{
    public T Key { get; private set; }

    public Group(T key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> GroupByComboboxName(this IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        Group<string> group = null;

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            if (parts.Length == 3 && parts[0] == "ComboBox" && parts[1] == "Name")
            {
                if (group != null) yield return group;
                group = new Group<string>(parts[2]);
            }
            else if (group != null)
            {
                group.Add(line);
            }
        }

        if (group != null) yield return group;
    } 
}
```

How to use it:

```
var lines = @"ComboBox Name cmbxOption

Classes Win32_1394Controller
Classes Win32_1394ControllerDevice

ComboBox Name cmbxStorage

Classes Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting
Classes Win32_TapeDrive".Split('\n').Select(l => l.TrimEnd('\r')).ToArray();

lines.GroupByComboboxName().ForEach(g =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key + ":");
    g.ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine("    " + l));
});
```

And the output it generates:

```
cmbxOption:
    Classes Win32_1394Controller
    Classes Win32_1394ControllerDevice
cmbxStorage:
    Classes Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting
    Classes Win32_TapeDrive
```

This should get you going.